# Play MP3 using Onclick listenmp3

Tags: javascript, flash, mp3, listen

I`m trying to listen a mp3 from a source that will be played in a player.swf

```
<script type="text/javascript">

e = canResizeFlash();
var so = new SWFObject("swf/player.swf", "mymovie", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "swf/expressinstall.swf");
so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
so.addVariable("allowResize", e);
so.addParam("menu", "false");
so.addParam("quality", "high");
so.write("playerSidebar");

</script>

<a href="audio source.mp3" onclick="this.className='listenMp3 listenMp3Ascultat'; return false;" title="Track title" class="listenMp3">
<strong>Track title</strong></a>
```

and this should be played when clicked on it but dont work.
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: SWF format is for Flash plugin & `href=` is talking to the browser (not plugins) so dont be surprised it's not working. Is **Player.swf** a downloaded file? Give us a link where you found this & we can check how to help you.

Comment: Hey VC. One, thank you for the replay. Please see this link: http://releasethesound.ro/v2/index.php and the player on the right RTS 5 Sets

Comment: I've checked it, that player isn't made with Flash. If true you should see "Flash Player Version" when you right-click on any part of the player (here it doesn't say so).